# Event handler for TDE decryption process in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, tde

Below code performs the decryption successfully but if the DB is huge it will take sometime to decrypt the DB

```
$sqlServer = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $sqlName
$ExistingDB=$sqlServer.Databases.Item($dbname) 
$ExistingDB.EncryptionEnabled=$false
$ExistingDB.Alter()
$ExistingDB.DatabaseEncryptionKey.Refresh()
$ExistingDB.DatabaseEncryptionKey.Drop()
```

I want to perform a backup once the decryption is completed. Is there an event handler for identifying the completion of DB decryption?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything that emits events in the object model for when encryption/decryption progress is made. But, you have two options.

1. the `$ExistingDB.DatabaseEncryptionKey.EncryptionState` is an enum that details whether the database is in transition to being encrypted/decrypted, is actually encrypted/decrypted, etc.
2. you can look at the `sys.dm_database_encryption_keys` system view. It has the same encryption state information provided above, but also has a percent_complete column that indicates progress during a transition.

Comment: Thank you for insights @Ben . Will use the second option